# Unable to retrieve json data using jQuery get

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to do a simple get query on JavaScript to retrieve a JSON string.

This is what I've tried:

```
  var response = $.get('https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json? 
  language=en') ;


  var answer = JSON.stringify(response);


  document.write(answer);
```

I am receiving the output : {"readyState":1}

I do not know what the problem is.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Not a duplicate. It's linked to my previous question which I have posted.

Comment: `$.get()` returns a Promise; it is not the content returned from the HTTP request.

Comment: `$.get` is an asynchronous call. You have the wait for the code to make the request before trying to use it's response.

Comment: Read the `$.get()` documentation!!

Comment: @charlietfl If you're going to tell someone to read the documentation, the least you can do is provide a [link to the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Comment: @Makyen Is it really that difficult to find?

Comment: @charlietfl Why did you close and then reopen this question? How is this *not* a duplicate of the canonical [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `function` in `$.get` which will serve as a callback for your request:

```
$.get( "https://uselessfacts.jsph.pl/random.json?language=en", function(data) {
  var answer = JSON.stringify(data);
  document.write(answer);
});
```

Comment: When a question is a duplicate, it's better to vote to close it as a duplicate, rather than answer it.

Comment: My bad, it was closed while I was answering.

Comment: Sorry about this question. Was very negligent of me.